# Debouncing root scope digest invocations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, digest

If I invoke `$scope.$apply()` ten times in immediate succession I presume ten root scope digests will occur.

Can we say that if the call to `$scope.$apply()` was debounced so that the trailing call was always completed that the final state of the application  would be the same as if the debounce was not in effect?

Can we say anything about the duration of successive root scope digests, given that a previous digest has just completed?

**Edit:**

I would like to clarify the purpose of my question.

Say I have a controller `MyController`, with an instance instantiated for each instance of a directive `MyDirective`.

These controller instances listen for an event `my-event` and trigger a root-scope digest each time `my-event` is raised.

Ten instances of `MyDirective` are rendered to the UI via an `ng-repeat`.

Another component raises an event `my-event`. Each of the ten `MyController` instances then trigger a root-scope digest.

If we put the sanity of this state of affairs to one side, my question is this: if I debounce the root-scope digest attempts made by `MyController`, and ensure that the trailing attempt always gets invoked, is the correctness of the program maintained?

```
var service = require('my-service');

function MyController($scope) {
  this._$scope = $scope;
  myService.on('my-event', this.triggerRootScopeDigest.bind(this));
}

MyController.prototype.triggerRootScopeDigest = function() {
  this._$scope.apply();
}
```

Comment: *"If I invoke $scope.$apply() ten times"*. You should not invoke it at all. And if you really need to (say, in custom directive event, socket, etc) then consider debouncing event handler in the first place.

Comment: It sounds like, though I may be wrong, you don't necessarily need a debounce but simply batching of the digest-cycle requests. Unless these are all based on user interaction, it's often the case that batching into one cycle works well. This can be done more simply by wrapping the tasks that call `$apply` in one of: `applyAsync`, `evalAsync` (if you don't mind the tasks all running in the current `$digest` cycle, if there is one), or otherwise `$timeout` if you want them to all fall in the next one.

Comment: @DRobinson, if you mean by "batching", grouping multiple root scope digest requests into one, then yes that is what I am talking about. You indicate that there is an idiomatic "batching" mechanism using `$timeout`?

Comment: @dfsq Given your comment, what is the alternative given a state change triggered outside of AngularJS?

Comment: Start at the source of these `$apply()` calls. Show some code. We have no way to know if using something like `$q.all()` might help or not

Comment: @Ben ahh for some reason I had it in my head that `$timeout` was batched. Not the case. The other two I suggested could work, though: http://jsfiddle.net/62jvLx3g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edited question still points to `$applyAsync` or `$evalAsync` as your solution.

Here's an example fiddle comparing both `$apply()` and `$applyAsync()`:
http://jsfiddle.net/635pvkkt/

You'll notice that 10 items are added via `ngRepeat`, each watching an `doApply` event, and an `doApplyAsync` event, to trigger the respective functions.

When you click the button that broadcasts the `doApply`, it triggers 10 `$digest` calls, each doing the directives work (in this case, as simple `console.log`).

The `doApplyAsync` broadcast, however, causes all 10 directives to do their work in a single `$digest`.

Of course, a debounced callback would also work. You could pass each directive a reference to a debounced function that is attached to a parent Controller's scope. If that debounce function works correctly and has a long enough debounce-time, it will only apply once. In some situations that's preferred, but the original question feels simple enough (assuming triggering a `$digest` is the main goal of the event) that substituting `$apply` for `$applyAsync` (or `$evalAsync`, depending on the semantics) seems more appropriate.

**EDIT:** Though the results are the exact same, this fiddle is more accurate as it triggers real DOM events on the elements directly: http://jsfiddle.net/uh9wxxho/